# My express app is not start,how can I do with it?

Tags: node.js

I created a Express application by `Express test` and then I `npm install`the package in test directory,but when I use `npm start`,my project can not run in my browser.Just like that:
[image]

This situation kept for a long time and I don't know how to deal with it.

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
  "dependencies": {
  "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
  "debug": "~2.6.3",
  "express": "~4.15.2",
  "jade": "~1.11.0",
  "morgan": "~1.8.1",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
```

}
}

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Your application is actually already running at that point. Just open `localhost:3000` in your browser.

Comment: Oh! thank you very much :) I thought it would console some information like "please visit localhost:3000 in your browser" :(

Comment: no problem :) so you don't get confused about that again in the future, you can update it to log that in the console once the server is now running. you can add a callback function to `.listen()` to do that :)